# Inverse Probability Fallacy of Maximum Likelihood Estimation

Tags: probability, mathematics, parameter-estimation

How can we justify that the parameters estimated via Maximum Likelihood Estimation are the optimal parameters for the data, given that MLE involves computing the data's likelihood as a function of the parameters and identifying the parameters that maximize this likelihood? Does this process not potentially fall into the inverse probability fallacy? The result of MLE does not inherently give the most likely parameters given the data, but it is often interpreted as so.

Is this, instead, a misinterpretation of MLE? Does MLE not yield the most likely parameters given the data?